# Is there a way to retrieve AWS Credentials information from AWS SDK?

Tags: c#, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, health-check

I'm trying to setup healthchecks for some required services to my dotnet core 3.1 API and I'm struggling on Amazon DynamoDB check.

We're using the [Xabaril healthcheck packages](https://github.com/Xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks) and the DynamoDb one ask for a DynamoDBOptions that requires the `AccessKey`, `SecretKey` and `RegionEndpoint`.

I know the AWS SDK get this information from the environment Credentials profile configuration:

```
using Amazon.DynamoDBv2;
//... other usings

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ... other stufs
    services.AddAWSService<IAmazonDynamoDB>();
    // ...
}
```

...But I need get it too in order to set up my dependency healthcheck like this:

```
    services.AddHealthChecks()
        .AddDynamoDb(dynamoDbOptions => 
            { 
                dynamoDbOptions .AccessKey = "<???>";
                dynamoDbOptions .RegionEndpoint = Amazon.RegionEndpoint.EUWest2; // <???>
                dynamoDbOptions .SecretKey = "<???>";
            }, "DynamoDB");
```

How can I get this `<???>` infos from AWS SDK packages?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After spend some more time in the official docs, I found the topic that covers exactly this need: [Accessing credentials and profiles in an application](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/creds-locate.html).

> To actively retrieve profiles and credentials, use classes from the `Amazon.Runtime.CredentialManagement namespace`.

In fact, we can use the `SharedCredentialsFile` class to find a profile in a file that uses the AWS credentials file format, the `NetSDKCredentialsFile` class to find a profile in the SDK Store or even `CredentialProfileStoreChain` to search in both.

You can see the examples in the link above. I got this in my case:

```
private static AWSCredentials GetAccountCredentials(string profileName = "default")
{
    var chain = new CredentialProfileStoreChain();
    if (chain.TryGetAWSCredentials(profileName, out AWSCredentials awsCredentials))
        return awsCredentials;

    // ToDo: Error Handler
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the AWS SDKs give programmatic access to IAM `AccessKey` and `SecretKey` credentials stored in the local [shared AWS credentials file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v3/developer-guide/creds-file.html).

I am not a c# dev, but perhaps see the .net sdk [`AWSCredentialsFactory.GetAWSCredentials`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/Runtime/TAWSCredentialsFactory.html) method or [this blogpost](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/credential-loading-and-the-aws-sdk-for-dotnet-deep-dive).

Comment: Thanks for check, I've found my way thru the docs. I've shared the code here in a more explicit way =)